# plug in jquery progreso boton

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente consulta, quiero hacer que se muestre una icono de progreso en un boton al presionarlo. el mismo hace una llamada ajax
 y luego de que se termine una llamada por ajax, quitar ese icono y estableccer el icono del boton que tenia por default. 
 Esto lo quiero hacer generico para todos los botones que hagan una llamada por ajax.
Estoy haciendo un plug in de jquery de la siguiente manera : el tema es que dependo de un js servicio y que todos los servicios
tengan el mismo nombre de metodo y hay que manejar parametros. No hay una manera mas prolija de hacer esto

tengo dos js un de AttendanceService.js y otro con el plug in :

```
$(#button1).setearSpinnerBtn("fa-fa-algo",AttendanceService);

function () {


    $.fn.setearSpinnerBtn = function (icon, AttendanceService) {
        var $that = this;
        this.click(function () {
            $that.disabled = true;
            if ($that.children("i")) {
                $that.children("i").classList = "fa fa-spinner fa-spin";
            }  

            AttendanceService.createAttendance('1', done, fail)

            var done = function () {
                alert("proceso ok ");
                $that.disabled = false;
                if ($that.children("i")) {
                    $that.children("i").classList = icon;
                }
            };

            var fail = function () {

                }
            };
        });
    }


})();

y en la clase servicio hago una llamada por post 

var AttendanceService = function () {
    var createAttendance = function (id, done, fail) {
        $.post("/api/attendances", { Id: idservice })
            .done(done)
            .fail(fail);
    };


    return {
        createAttendance: createAttendance,
            }
}();
```

cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida

Comment: ¿has probado enviar como parámetro una [promise](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) ?

Comment: gracias jose A Fernandez es lo que necesitaba